# How to set Storyboard.TargetProperty in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I am developing wpf application in C#. The following xaml code is working fine for me.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
        <VisualState x:Name="DefaultVisualState">
            <Storyboard/>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="FocusVisualState">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="CircleEllipse1">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF0004FF"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock1">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFBCB0B0"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

The same code I have written in C#

```
EasingColorKeyFrame easingColorKeyFrameObj = new EasingColorKeyFrame();
easingColorKeyFrameObj.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
easingColorKeyFrameObj.Value = Colors.Red;
ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesObj = new ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesObj.KeyFrames.Add(easingColorKeyFrameObj);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesObj, "CircleEllipse1");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
    colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesObj, new PropertyPath("Color"));

Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
myStoryboard.Children.Add(colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesObj);

myStoryboard.Begin(this, true);
```

In the above code how should I set the `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"` and `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"` in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify it as a string

```
private void AnimateColor(string ellipseName, Color ellipseColor, string textBlockName, Color textBlockColor)
            {
                EasingColorKeyFrame easingColorKeyFrameEllipseObj = new EasingColorKeyFrame();
                easingColorKeyFrameEllipseObj.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12));
                easingColorKeyFrameEllipseObj.Value = ellipseColor;

                ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesEllipseObj = new ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                Storyboard.SetTargetName(colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesEllipseObj, ellipseName);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
                    colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesEllipseObj, new PropertyPath("(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"));
                colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesEllipseObj.KeyFrames.Add(easingColorKeyFrameEllipseObj);

                EasingColorKeyFrame easingColorKeyFrameTextBlockObj = new EasingColorKeyFrame();
                easingColorKeyFrameTextBlockObj.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12));
                easingColorKeyFrameTextBlockObj.Value = textBlockColor;

                ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesTextBlockObj = new ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                Storyboard.SetTargetName(colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesTextBlockObj, textBlockName);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
                    colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesTextBlockObj, new PropertyPath("(TextElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"));
                colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesTextBlockObj.KeyFrames.Add(easingColorKeyFrameTextBlockObj);


                Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

                storyboard.Children.Add(colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesEllipseObj);
                storyboard.Children.Add(colorAnimationUsingKeyFramesTextBlockObj);

                storyboard.Begin(this, true);
            }
```